# Check the Entire Property of Three Complex Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, entire-functions

I am working on a question asking me to find which of the following three functions are entire.

> (1) $$f(z):=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{e^{z^{2}t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt$$
>
> (2) $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^{n^{2}}}{(n!)^{2}}$$
>
> (3)$$\dfrac{\sin^{2}z}{z(e^{iz}-1)}.$$

**I made some progress in (1), had no idea about (2), and proved (3).**

**For (1):**

replace $u=t^{1/2}$ so that $$t=u^{2},\ dt=2t^{1/2}du,\  t=0\implies u=0,\  t=1\implies u=1,$$ and thus the original integral can be re-written as $$f(z):=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{e^{z^{2}t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt=2\int_{0}^{1}e^{u^{2}z^{2}}du.$$

Now we use power series to expand the integrand, so that we have 
\begin{align*}
f(z)&=2\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(u^{2}z^{2})^{n}}{n!}du\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Big(\dfrac{z^{2n}}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}u^{2n}du\Big)\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)n!}.
\end{align*}

**However, I don't know if I can directly conclude here that it is entire, or I have to "return" the power series back as a function, since this new series may not converge..**

**For (2):**

No idea..which power series should I use? I tried something similar to $e^{z}$, but had a hard time to create $z^{n^{2}}$ and $(n!)^{2}$.

**For (3):**

Using power series, we can see that $$z(e^{iz}-1)=z\Big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^{n}}{n!}-1\Big)=z^{2}\Big(i+\frac{(i)^{2}z}{2!}+\cdots\Big),$$ where $\Big(i+\frac{(i)^{2}z}{2!}+\cdots\Big)$ is a non-vanishing holomorphic function on a neighborhood of $z_{0}=0$.

Therefore, the fraction $\dfrac{1}{z(e^{iz}-1)}$ has a pole at $z_{0}=0$ of order $2$.

However, using power series, we also have $$\sin^{2}z=\Big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}z^{2n+1}\Big)^{2}=z^{2}(1-z^{2}+z^{4}-\cdots)^{2}, $$ where $(1-z^{2}+z^{4}-\cdots)^{2}$ is a non-vanishing holomorphic function on a neighborhood of $z_{0}=0$.

Therefore, $\sin^{2}z$ has a zero at $z_{0}=0$ of order $2$.

Thus, the original fraction can be re-written as $$f(z):=\dfrac{\sin^{2}z}{z(e^{iz}-1)}=\dfrac{(1-z^{2}+z^{4}-\cdots)^{2}}{(i+\frac{(i)^{2}z}{2!}+\cdots)},$$ whence entire.

Thank you in advance for any hints, ideas or corrections of my finished proof!

**Edit 1:**

As what was discussed between me and **Jose Carlos Santos**, for part (2), Santos said that the series converges everywhere. However, after doing some calculation, I found that the radius of convergence is $1$. Thus, I posted my computation in this edition so that Santos and other users can have a look at it and point out where I got wrong.

Set $a_{n}:=\dfrac{1}{(n!)^{2}}$. Then the ratio test says that the series converges if $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big|\dfrac{a_{n+1}(z-0)^{(n+1)^{2}}}{a_{n}(z-0)^{n^{2}}}\Big|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big|\dfrac{z^{2n+1}}{(n+1)^{2}}\Big|<1, $$ so that the radius of convergence is $$|z-0|:=r=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n+1)^{2/(2n+1)}.$$

Set $x_{n}=(n+1)^{2/(2n+1)}$. Then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\log x_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{2\log(n+1)}{2n+1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{n+1}=0.$$

This implies that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=1.$$

Thus, the radius of convergence is $r=1$, and thus the function is not entire.

**Edit 2:**

As confirmed by **Jose Carlos Santos**, the solution in **Edit 1** is correct.

Thus totally we have $(1)$ and $(3)$ entire and $(2)$ not entire with radius of convergence $=1$.

I'd like to express my appreciation to everyone who is participated in this post, especially to **Jose Carlos Santos** who patiently answered all my dumb questions.

Comment: For 1, what happened to the $z^2$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I will edit it right away, sorry for the typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What you did is fine and, since the series that you got converges everywhere, its sum is an entire function.
2. This series converges everywhere (by the ratio test), and therefore its sum is entire.
3. The zeros of the numerator ar the entire multiples of $\pi$ and all of them are double zeros. The zeros of the denominator are the integer multiples of $2\pi$ and all of them are simple zeros, except for $0$, which is a double zero. So, every zero of the denominator is also a zero of the numerator and its order as a zero of the denominatir is never greater than its order as a zero of the denominator. Therefore, every singularity of the quotient is a removable one and so the quotient can be extended to one and only one entire function.

Comment: So for (1), I also need to do a ratio test to see the radius of convergence, right?

Comment: That is how I would do it.

Comment: okay. got you! Thank you so much! I forgot to test the convergence directly...

Comment: For (3), is my proof correct? or our arguments are actually equivalent?

Comment: No, your argument is not correct. By that argument, the tangent function would be entire too. But it is not; it has poles at the numbers of the form $\frac\pi2+k\pi$ ($k\in\mathbb Z$). You need to check the the order of every zero of the denominator never exceeds its order as a zero of the denominator.

Comment: Got you. Thank you so much!

Comment: By the way, I think you mean "the order of every zero of the denominator never exceeds its order as a zero of the numerator".

Comment: Oops! Yes, sure.

Comment: I am sorry for getting back to you again. I did the calculation for part (2), but it shows that the radius of convergence is $1$. I will add my calculation in the edition of the post.

Comment: You are right! I am so sorry. I was sloppy in my computations.

Comment: No Problem. Thank you so much!